# My gmail is going to my boyfriends phone

Tags: gmail

how can I disconnect my boyfriend from my gmail. He says he is going to and still has not. He on his way over now and thought I might be able to do something

Answer (score 5):

Go to [myaccount.google.com](http://myaccount.google.com).

Scroll down to `Recent Activity`>`Devices`.
Click on any device your account should not be associated with and then click `Remove`.

Then scroll down to `Connected Apps and Services`>`Account Permissions`. Click `View All`. Select any app or device that should not be accessing your data and click `Revoke Access`.

It's a good idea to go ahead and run though the security check at the top of the accounts page. As others have mentioned, you may want to go ahead and reset your password, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think your friend has enabled (in your Gmail) email forwarding to his email address. You can easily disable this forwarding, if this happens to be the case, but requires desktop view of Gmail IMO. Google has a guide to enable/disable email forwarding. Click [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957) to see the guide.

That said, I cannot claim that the above solution will help to resolve the issue if you're using some custom app (other than [Gmail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm) or [Inbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.inbox) app) on Android or PC  to access your emails.

---

<sup>Note: Google mostly takes care of its guides and links,and so, I don't think I need to mention those steps here at all.</sup>

Comment: Do note that the issue will persist if your friend has access to your email password, since he can reset the settings, read the emails, send them, delete from Sent items, and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Log in to gmail and change your password.  This will stop his phone accessing your gmail.